# Problem with nomenclature

Tags: texmaker, acronyms, nomenclature

I am trying to get a list of abbreviations into my paper using the

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
```

package. However, I won't create a list in my document when I type

```
\printnomenclature
```

Can anyone please help? I am very new to Tex, so please help me out.
The documentation says I have to run `makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls`
I have no idea what this means, nor do I know where to type this or what filename to enter.

My file looks like this, and I am typing in TexMaker:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature

\nomenclature{AIMR}{Association for Investment Management and Research}

blablabla AIMR

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to run: `makeindex.exe <path to your tex file>\yourtexfile.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <path to your tex file>\yourtexfile.nls`. Run `pdflatex` then `above command` and then `pdflatex`.

Comment: Does your TeXMaker offer the compilation method "arara"? If it does, just write `% arara: pdflatex "Enter" % arara: nomencl "Enter" % arara: pdflatex` on the very top of your main file. "Enter" means: press Enter, don't type it. Than you can compile with arara instead of PDFLaTeX and everything works fine.

Comment: My TexMaker does not offer arara. Also, concerning Harish's response, where do I have to run it? Do I have to create a text file? Do I open cmd? I literally have no idea what that means. Could you please provide step-by-step help? What programs do I use for running?

Comment: Also, there is no .nlo or .ist file in my folder.

Comment: So I managed to understandwhat "run" means. I entered makeindex.exe <path to your tex file>\yourtexfile.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <path to your tex file>\yourtexfile.nls into cmd and it created a .nlo and a .ist file. However, I still can't get it to create a abbreviations list in my output file.

Comment: @ThomasH. I added an answer. Leave a comment, if any more details are needed.

Answer (score 3):

This is going to be long...

## From command prompt:

Let us say that your tex file (file.tex) is in `D:\my folder`. Open `file.tex` in texmaker and choose `pdflatex` in the build list, compile. Now open command prompt (Start→ run → cmd). In the command prompt that opens type

```
makeindex.exe D:\my folder\file.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o D:\my folder\file.nls
```

Now go back to texmaker and again compile with `pdflatex` using build button.

## Using `arara`:

Download and install arara. Make sure that `arara.exe` is in system path. (while installing, the installer asks this option. Choose *yes*).

Now open texmaker. Using the menu go to `User` → `User Commands` → `Edit User Commands` as in the picture.

[image]

Now the following window will open. Type `Arara` in `Menu Item` and `arara %` under `Command` as shown. Now on the left hand side `Command 1: Arara` should appear as below

[image]

Press `OK`. Now in the build list an entry with `arara` should appear as shown. Choose it.

[image]

Now add following lines to your `file.tex`:

```
%% this is file.tex. Following three lines need to be added.
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% copy the formatting of section titles
\let\nomencl@section\section
% if the level is greater than 1000, then amsart
% doesn't include the section's title in the toc
\patchcmd{\nomencl@section}{{1}}{{1001}}{}{}
% patch \thenomenclature to call \nomencl@section
% instead of \section*
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
  {\section*}
  {\nomencl@section}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Notations}
\makenomenclature

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\nomenclature[000]{$Hi$}{World}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\printnomenclature[1in]

\section{world}
\end{document}
```

Now press `Build` button which reads `1: Arara` as below:

[image]

Hope it is all done well. :-)

Comment: It still won't work. I'm really in over my head here. I will just manually type all abbreviations, using the tabbing-environment. Thank you all for your effort.

Comment: @ThomasH. `won't work` doesn't help. Please give details. Typing by hands is bad. Also try to post your tex code. Does my code work?

Comment: @ThomasH. Don't give up ;-)

Comment: I would like to add this as a comment to Harish Kumar answer but is my first day here and I can't. I want to share something that worked for me (Windows 8 user)
I did exactlye what Harish said about the command prompt but, being on the root folder of the project. So sumarizing the process that worked for me it would be(assuming that the tex file is in "C:\Myfolder\file.tex" - Open your 'file.tex' in TexMaker and compile it with pdflatex - Open de comand prompt in your root folder "C:\Myfolder" or open it anywhere and type "cd C:\Myfolder". - Once you are in that folder type "makeindex.exe file

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of Texmaker is that it allows you to do without the command prompt. And it is not necessary to go through `arara` either.There are several ways to do this.

**Change the command of the `MakeIndex` button**

If you use the button below to launch the compilers one by one you just need to change the `MakeIndex` button command.

[image]

To do this you must go to *Options - Configure Texmaker - Commands*. And must change the command corresponding to `MakeIndex` to :

```
makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg
```

All you have to do is use the button to compile once with `PDFLaTeX`, once with `MakeIndex` and once more with `PDFLaTeX`.

**Create a customized Quick Build**

If you prefer to use the Quick Build button (or press the F1 key) rather than pressing the buttons calling the compilers a lot of times you can edit what the Quick Build button do.

Go to *Options - Configure Texmaker - Quick Build* and create your own command with the wizard. For example, for operations `PDFLaTeX + BibTeX + MakeIndex + PDFLaTeX x2 + View PDF` I got the following command :

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|bibtex %.aux|makeindex %.idx|pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|evince %.pdf
```

Warning, if you have modified the MakeIndex call command, you still need to modify this last command line. All you have to do is replace in the command line `makeindex %.idx` by `makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg`. Now your Quick Build will work with `nomencl`.

**Create a customized command**

If you prefer use customized command rather than Quick Build, go to *User - User Commands - Edit User Commands* and create your own command with the wizard ; then replace in the command line `makeindex %.idx` by `makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg`.